# Are managers allowed to send reference letters unrequested?

Tags: united-states, recommendation-letter

I work as a teacher. I left my job because of poor management, a feeling that many other teachers shared, and at least 15 others left for the same reason. While applying for another job, I requested reference letters from three staff.

In the previous job, I had one manager who regarded me as a protégé, and so micromanaged my work, and became angry if I had my own ideas and did something different. I did not request any reference letter from her, as she was always at extremes, either praising my work, or becoming angry to the point of screaming at me, if I did something original.

I found out that this manager sent a letter to my current manager, with suggestions about what to watch out for. Is it permissible for someone to essentially write a reference letter when I never requested it?

Comment: So, you're upset that someone put in a good word for you?

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter do we know if it's a "good word", or some weird misguided 'warning' to the new manager that the OP is  a trouble maker?

Comment: So you’re basically asking if it’s permissible that people *talk* to each other ?

Comment: That would entirely depend on the contents of the letter.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: @DanPichelman Perhaps it's the fact that the OP called it a reference letter, and not "slanderous statements" or indicate in any way that this was malicious.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are not enough details, such as location or whether the action taken was harmful

Comment: `Is that kind of action permissible?` - Are you asking if it's legally permissible? Why would it not be? What law do you imagine might have been broken?

Comment: Question is, why they in the first place take initiative without being asked. Second question is why an employer would even accept reference letters from people they didn't ask. Third question is the quality of the letter in regard of the contents. Did they praise you? Did they say bad/wrong things?

Comment: You did not include your country!!

Answer (score 3):

They can send the email but it might have repercussions for them. If they give you anything less than a glowing recommendation it might open them up to legal action, for example.

You should consider why this person sent the email. If it is negative the reason is obvious and hopefully your current employer will see that they have a grudge and ignore it. If it is positive then maybe it's an olive branch, maybe they are trying to get out as well and hoping you might recommend them.